# Why do I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS right after instantiation?

Tags: swift, debugging, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41838591/crash-in-geocode-call) and still can't figure out something. I placed breakpoints at AA & BB and saw that first AA happens which means `destinationPlacemark` gets instantiated. later at line BB I `po destinationPlacemark` and get error :

> expression produced error: error: Execution was interrupted, reason:
>   EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10). The process has been returned
>   to the state before expression evaluation.

I read some of the answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received) but they are talking about a released object. How can that object be released as quickly as such?!

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {


var destinationPlacemark = CLPlacemark() //AA

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() //BB
    forwardGeocoding(address: "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014")
}
func forwardGeocoding(address: String) {
CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error ?? "Error in plscement conversion")
        return
    }
    if (placemarks?.count)! > 0 {
        let placemark = placemarks?[0]
        let location = self.destinationPlacemark.location
        let coordinate = location?.coordinate
        print("Latitude: \(coordinate!.latitude), Longitude: \(coordinate!.longitude)")

        self.destinationPlacemark = placemark!
    }
})
}

}
```

Comment: I _suspect_ that the reason is that you are not supposed to instantiate `CLPlacemark` just like that, via the constructor.  You only can get it from the geocoder (like in the example).  `CLPlacemark` is bridged from Obj-C where it inherits from `NSObject` that does provide you with zero-argument initializer, yes, however that one immediately returns null object.

Answer (score -1):

as explained in [the answer in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41838591/crash-in-geocode-call?noredirect=1#comment70865378_41838591) `destinationPlacemark = CLPlacemark()` was instantiated but has no location specified. Then location is being set to this nil. I posted the original question. Try chaning `let location = self.destinationPlacemark.location` to `location = placemark.location`

Comment: See the comment on the question